# Parallelize openalex API

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, parallel-processing

I am using the openalex API [see here for an example](https://github.com/ourresearch/openalex-api-tutorials/blob/main/notebooks/getting-started/paging.ipynb) to get all the papers of 2020.
The way I am doing this is the following:

```
import requests

# url with a placeholder for cursor

example_url_with_cursor ='https://api.openalex.org/works?filter=publication_year:2020&cursor={}'

dfs=defaultdict(dict)
paper_id=[]
title_lst=[]
year_lst=[]
lev_lst=[]

page=1
cursor = '*'

# loop through pages
while cursor:
    
    # set cursor value and request page from OpenAlex
    url = example_url_with_cursor.format(cursor)
    print("\n" + url)
    page_with_results = requests.get(url).json()
    
    # loop through partial list of results
    results = page_with_results['results']
    for i,work in enumerate(results):
        openalex_id = work['id'].replace("https://openalex.org/", "")
        if work['display_name'] is not None and len(work['display_name'])>0:
            openalex_title = work['display_name']
        else:
            openalex_title='No title'
        #openalex_author = work['authorships'][0]['author']['display_name']
        openalex_year = work['publication_year']
        if work['concepts'] is not None and  len(work['concepts'])>0:
            openalex_lev = work['concepts'][0]['display_name']
        else:
            openalex_lev = 'None'
        paper_id.append(openalex_id)
        title_lst.append(openalex_title)
        year_lst.append(openalex_year)
        lev_lst.append(openalex_lev)
        #Constructing a pandas db:
        df=pd.DataFrame(paper_id, columns=['paper_id'])
        df['title'] = title_lst
        df['level'] = lev_lst
        df['pub_year'] = year_lst
        #print(openalex_id, end='\t' if (i+1)%5!=0 else '\n')

    # update cursor to meta.next_cursor
    #page += 1
    #dfs[page]=df
    cursor = page_with_results['meta']['next_cursor']
```

This method,, however is very slow and I would like to speed it up a bit through parallelization. Since I am quite new to parallelizing while loops I would kindly ask you if there is a way to do so without messing up the final results.
Specifically, the code above is looping through different data pages, picking up the cursor of the next page, saving the data in a dataframe (df) and going to the next page. The process is repeated until the last page with a cursor in it.

Comment: Is the code correctly indented? If yes, then why do you add increasingly bigger lists to a new dataframe that is unused in the end? It seems `requests.get(url)` takes the major part of the time. Doing parallel request might be faster (or not since the website may compute them serially or be saturated), but the website could banish you if you do too many requests. Async request may be a good alternative but the saturation/ban may still be an issue.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for the comment. The reason why I am doing increasingly bigger lists is that I don't know yet how the website works. Therefore as a starter code I checked how every list was updated. I agree with you that I can now rewrite this part. Concerning async and parallel could you please provide a MWE?

Comment: I did not used async since years (it was before the introduction of the keyword in the languages so the old API are now super-seeded by newer ones). I just found https://pypi.org/project/requests-async/ with a quick search. Looks like promising.

Answer (score 0):

I am on the OpenAlex team, and I can help with this.

Paralellizing your requests is unlikely to help speed things up. There are a few things you could try, though. You can [join the polite pool](https://docs.openalex.org/how-to-use-the-api/rate-limits-and-authentication#the-polite-pool) by including the `mailto=<YOUR_EMAIL>` parameter to identify yourself in all of your requests. You can also use the [`per-page=200`](https://docs.openalex.org/how-to-use-the-api/get-lists-of-entities/paging) parameter to get more works returned in each page.

Getting all of the papers in 2020 (more than 10 million papers) will take a while, probably half a day at least. [The API allows 100,000 requests per day](https://docs.openalex.org/how-to-use-the-api/rate-limits-and-authentication) on the free tier. While you could do this all in one day, you'll start getting close to the limit, and you might want to consider spreading out your data collection over several days, or starting off with a smaller set of works.